# Can I have local state in a Kafka Processor?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I've been reading a bit about the Kafka concurrency model, but I still struggle to understand whether I can have local state in a Kafka Processor, or whether that will fail in bad ways?

My use case is: I have a topic of updates, I want to insert these updates into a database, but I want to batch them up first. I batch them inside a Java ArrayList inside the Processor, and send them and commit them in the punctuate call.

Will this fail in bad ways? Am I guaranteed that the ArrayList will not be accessed concurrently?

I realize that there will be multiple Processors and multiple ArrayLists, depending on the number of threads and partitions, but I don't really care about that.

I also realize I will loose the ArrayList if the application crashes, but I don't care if some events are inserted twice into the database.

This works fine in my simple tests, but is it correct? If not, why?

Comment: so if i understand, your java application will consume from updates topic right?

Comment: @Deadpool yes, the Kafka topic contains updates for the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you use for local state in your Kafka consumer application is up to you. So, you can guarantee only the current thread/consumer will be able to access the local state data in your array list.  If you have multiple threads, one per Kafka consumer, each thread can have their own private ArrayList or hashmap to store state into.  You could also have something like a local RocksDB database for persistent local state.

A few things to look out for:

- If you're batching updates together to send to the DB, are those updates in any way related, say, because they're part of a transaction?  If not, you might run into problems. An easy way to ensure this is the case is to set a key for your messages with a transaction ID, or some other unique identifier for the transaction, and that way all the updates with that transaction ID will end up in one specific partition, so whoever consumes them is sure to always have the

  - How are you validating that you got *ALL* the transactions before your batch update? Again, this is important if you're dealing with database updates inside transactions.  You could simply wait for a pre-determined amount of time to ensure you have all the updates (say, maybe 30 seconds is enough in your case). Or maybe you send an "EndOfTransaction" message that details how many messages you should have gotten, as well as maybe a CRC or hash of the messages themselves.  That way, when you get it, you can either use it to validate you have all the messages already, or you can keep waiting for the ones that you haven't gotten yet.
  - Make sure you're not committing to Kafka the messages you're keeping in memory until *after* you've batched and sent them to the database, and you have confirmed that the updates went through successfully.  This way, if your application dies, the next time it comes back up, it will get again the messages you haven't committed in Kafka yet.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! My updates are not related in any way, so I don't have to think about grouping them. I'm interested in the case of using the Processor API specifically though. I've implemented a `Processor<KeyType, UpdateType>` that has local state, but I'm not 100% sure if the Processor is thread safe?